# Cannot see my custom UserControl in my StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am having some issue with seeing the custom UserControl I built in my MainWindow.

CustomControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="LearnWPF.CustomControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="262" Width="168">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}">
    <TextBox Name="txt_TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"/>
    <TextBox Name="txt_TextBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"/>
    <ComboBox  Name="lst_Dropdown" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listContents}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rad_RadioBtn1" Content="{Binding rad_RadBtn1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,133,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rad_RadioBtn2" Content="{Binding rad_RadBtn2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rad_RadioBtn3" Content="{Binding rad_RadBtn3}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rad_RadioBtn4" Content="{Binding rad_RadBtn4}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
</Grid>
```

CustomControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public string txt_Field1 { get; set; }
    public string txt_Field2 { get; set; }
    public string rad_RadBtn1 { get; set; }
    public string rad_RadBtn2 { get; set; }
    public string rad_RadBtn3 { get; set; }
    public string rad_RadBtn4 { get; set; }
    public string[] listContents { get; set; }

    public CustomControl()
    {
        listContents = new string[5] { "Slot 1", "Slot 2", "Slot 3", "Slot 4", "Slot 5" };
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Name="CFG_MainWindow" x:Class="LearnWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test Best Data - Custom File Generator" Height="464.5" Width="950">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Load Template" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98"/>
    <Button Content="Add Col" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,36,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button x:Name="Generate_Data" Content="Generate Data Window" Height="22" Margin="0,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="Generate_Data_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl Name="userControlContainer" Margin="10,150,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UserControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomControl> MyCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<CustomControl>();
        MyCollection.Add(new CustomControl { txt_Field1 = "Test 1", txt_Field2 = "Test 2", rad_RadBtn1 = "Rad1", rad_RadBtn2 = "Rad2", rad_RadBtn3 = "Rad3", rad_RadBtn4 = "Rad4" });
        MyCollection.Add(new CustomControl { txt_Field1 = "Test 3", txt_Field2 = "Test 4", rad_RadBtn1 = "Rad1", rad_RadBtn2 = "Rad2", rad_RadBtn3 = "Rad3", rad_RadBtn4 = "Rad4" });
        MyCollection.Add(new CustomControl { txt_Field1 = "Test 5", txt_Field2 = "Test 6", rad_RadBtn1 = "Rad1", rad_RadBtn2 = "Rad2", rad_RadBtn3 = "Rad3", rad_RadBtn4 = "Rad4" });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Where in the MainWindow did you put the UserControl? There is just an ItemsControl named like a UserControl

Comment: @schlonzo He's got a collection of that control in his viewmodel.

Comment: @TalenKylon Don't put a collection of controls in your viewmodel. Your viewmodel should be the data items, whatever they are. You instantiate multiple controls by giving your ItemsControl an ItemTemplate.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I appreciate the advice. I believe what you're referring to is the MVVM I've been reading about? Yep, I do plan to go that route at some point, but for right now I'm just trying to get it to show up.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Oh, you're right. But I think the UserControl should be placed within the ItemsPanelTemplate in xaml

Comment: @schlonzo I made a change to MainWindow.XAML trying to implement what (I think) you're talking about but I'm still not seeing anything.

Comment: @TalenKylon try swapping the <UserControl DataContext="{Binding}" /> with <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>

Comment: @matt No luck with that.

Comment: @TalenKylon where are you setting the datacontext of MainWindow?

Comment: @matt I am not setting the datacontext of MainWindow anywhere. Where is the proper place to set this, and what am I setting it to?

Comment: With the way you're trying to do things, put DataContext = this; at the end of the MainWindow constructor. By default the DataContext is null, so the Binding you're trying to use in the XAML won't work without a data context being set.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I tried adding that line to the end of the MainWindow constructor and still no luck. I tried before and after InitializeComponent();.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binding the Datacontext needs to be set to some object, as it is null by default. Otherwise the binding you are trying to setup in the XAML is basically just a string with no context on how to find the property.

Your CustomControl needs to call InitializeComponent() in order to setup the XAML.

You can use `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>`, in order to have the binding provide the control type to display. As you get more into MVVM you could also use an [IValueConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/868163/IValueConverter-Example-and-Usage-in-WPF) with the binding to get more separation from the UI code.

CustomControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public string txt_Field1 { get; set; }
    public string txt_Field2 { get; set; }
    public string rad_RadBtn1 { get; set; }
    public string rad_RadBtn2 { get; set; }
    public string rad_RadBtn3 { get; set; }
    public string rad_RadBtn4 { get; set; }
    public string[] listContents { get; set; }

    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listContents = new string[5] { "Slot 1", "Slot 2", "Slot 3", "Slot 4", "Slot 5" };
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Name="CFG_MainWindow" x:Class="LearnWPF.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Test Best Data - Custom File Generator" Height="464.5" Width="950">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Load Template" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98"/>
    <Button Content="Add Col" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,36,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button x:Name="Generate_Data" Content="Generate Data Window" Height="22" Margin="0,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="Generate_Data_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl Name="userControlContainer" Margin="10,150,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomControl> MyCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<CustomControl>();
        MyCollection.Add(new CustomControl { txt_Field1 = "Test 1", txt_Field2 = "Test 2", rad_RadBtn1 = "Rad1", rad_RadBtn2 = "Rad2", rad_RadBtn3 = "Rad3", rad_RadBtn4 = "Rad4" });
        MyCollection.Add(new CustomControl { txt_Field1 = "Test 3", txt_Field2 = "Test 4", rad_RadBtn1 = "Rad1", rad_RadBtn2 = "Rad2", rad_RadBtn3 = "Rad3", rad_RadBtn4 = "Rad4" });
        MyCollection.Add(new CustomControl { txt_Field1 = "Test 5", txt_Field2 = "Test 6", rad_RadBtn1 = "Rad1", rad_RadBtn2 = "Rad2", rad_RadBtn3 = "Rad3", rad_RadBtn4 = "Rad4" });
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```